Hangfire UI - An error was encountered while handling the remote login. Correlation failed
I am trying to configure Hangfire UI with my .net app. I created very tiny .net application. Here is the code:
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddAuthorization(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddPolicy("Hangfire", cfgPolicy =>
                {
                    cfgPolicy.AddRequirements().RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    cfgPolicy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                });
            })
            .AddAuthentication(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                cfg.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Authority = "authority";
                cfg.ClientId = "clientId";
                cfg.ClientSecret = "secret";
                cfg.ResponseType = "code";
                cfg.UsePkce = true;

                cfg.Scope.Clear();
                cfg.Scope.Add("openid");
                cfg.Scope.Add("profile");

                cfg.SaveTokens = true;
            });

        services.AddHangfire(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseSqlServerStorage("connection string", new SqlServerStorageOptions
            {
                CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                DisableGlobalLocks = true
            });
        });

        services.AddHangfireServer();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard().RequireAuthorization("Hangfire");
        });
    }
}

I’ve also created dedicated application in auth0 dedicated for Hangfire UI. It works locally but after deploying it to the environment I am getting following error:
Show raw exception details
System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
 ---> System.Exception: Correlation failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Any suggestion how to solve it?
I tried to change cookies settings.
